# How to align 2 react native elements, 1 being in the center and 1 on the beginning

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

Lets assume that we have those react native styles:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  parentView:{
    width: 400,
    height:150
  },
  containerView:{
    flex:1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor:'black'
  },
  child1:{
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    alignSelf: 'flex-start'
  },
  child2: {
    backgroundColor: 'yellow'
  }
}
```

and that we have this render function:

```
render: function(){
  return(
      <View style={styles.parentView}>
        <View style={styles.containerView}>
          <Text style={styles.child1}>Child1</Text>
          <Text style={styles.child2}>Child2</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );  
}
```

This code produces this image:
[image: WRONG]

but what I want to achieve is this image:
[image]

**VERY VERY IMPORTANT**: I want `child2` to be **TOTALLY** centered within the `containerView`, and not a bit far to the right because of the space that `child1` occupies.

How can I achieve that in react-native?*

p.s.: Keep in mind that this will run on many resolutions (many screens with different aspect ratios) thus, it cannot be set in an absolute way that would result on it only working on "some" screens but not on others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it works for me

```
render() {
    return(
      <View style={styles.parentView}>
      <View style={styles.containerView}>
        <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
          <View style={styles.rowItem}>
            <Text style={styles.child1}>Child1</Text>
          </View>
         <View style={styles.rowItem}>
            <Text style={styles.child2}>Child2</Text>
         </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  parentView:{
    width: 400,
    height:150
  },
  containerView:{
    flex:1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor:'black'
  },
  rowContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  rowItem:{
    flex: 1
  },
  child1:{
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    position: 'absolute',
  },
  child2: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'yellow'
  }
});
```

Comment: also check out the [React Native Dimenstions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html), you'll be able to get the dimensions of the window with something like
`var {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');`

Comment: This works, but I don't understand why. Would you be kind enough to explain a bit why this works in your answer Wesley?

Comment: So im guessing you understand the containerView style since that was pretty close if not exactly your code. the view with rowContainer just switches the flex direction from row to column to make centering items horizontally easier. since child1 is positioned absolutely it will default to the top left of its parent view and will also allow child2 to take use the whole row to calculate its center.

Comment: Oh awesome. I thought `flexDirection` applied strictly to the element you specify it to, and not to its children. Am I right to believe that it passes down to the children of the element that you use it,  therefore explains why we need a different container to change the direction again?

Comment: yes, flexDirection defines the direction for items inside (ie children) that container. im assuming its inherited by its children, i tend to set it when i am expecting specific behavior.

Comment: Awesome, thanks to you I wrote this library https://github.com/SudoPlz/sp-react-native-iconbutton that is a button which contains an icon as well within it. Thank you very much.