# How to align one component to left and other to right (end of page) react native?

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I'm making an app in React Native and I want align a circle with the end of page.

I want to make this:

[image: I want make this]

But it's currently like this and only stays this way:

[image: But only stay this way]

The complete view:

[[image: The complete view]]

I already tried alignSelf, justifyContent and others but it doesn't work.
I tested this: [How to align 2 react native elements, 1 being in the center and 1 on the beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36204061/how-to-align-2-react-native-elements-1-being-in-the-center-and-1-on-the-beginni)

But it won't work.

My code:

```
const ListProductsHeader = () => (
<View>
    <View style={style.containerInfo}>
        <View style={style.circle} />
        <View>
            <Text style={style.unityName}>SUPERMERCADO MACCARTNEY</Text>
            <Text style={style.subInfo}>Categoria: Mercado</Text>
            <Text style={style.subInfo}>Pedido Nº: 1245</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
    <View style={style.containerProducts}>
        <Text style={style.productName}>1x 42 - Coca Cola 2L</Text>
        <View style={style.minus}></View>
    </View>


</View>
);
```

CSS:

```
containerProducts:{
paddingTop: 40,
paddingLeft: 15,
flexDirection: 'row',
 },
productName: {
  alignSelf: 'flex-start',
},
minus:{
  width: 20,
  height: 20,
  borderRadius: 20/2,
  backgroundColor: 'red',
},
containerInfo:{
  paddingTop:15,
  flexDirection:'row',
  paddingLeft: 15,
},
unityName:{
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  paddingLeft: 15,
},
subInfo:{
  color: 'gray',
  paddingLeft: 15,
},
circle: {
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  borderRadius: 50/2,
  backgroundColor: 'red',
  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
},
```

Comment: `<View>
            <Text style={style.unityName}>SUPERMERCADO MACCARTNEY</Text>
            <Text style={style.subInfo}>Categoria: Mercado</Text>
            <Text style={style.subInfo}>Pedido Nº: 1245</Text>
        </View>`

BTW where should these items come, I cant see them in the image

Comment: I will put the all the screen in the question.

Comment: Does adding `justifyContent: 'space-between',` to `containerProducts` fix it?

Comment: @MattAft no, still the same way :/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Lkke to suggest one thing that can help you with this problem
what you need to do is. Everthing is correct except the main view css

```js
    <View style={flexDirection:'row',justifyContent : 'space-between'}>
     <View style={style.circle} />
        <View>
            <Text style={style.unityName}>SUPERMERCADO MACCARTNEY</Text>
            <Text style={style.subInfo}>Categoria: Mercado</Text>
            <Text style={style.subInfo}>Pedido Nº: 1245</Text>
        </View>
     </View>
     <View style={style.containerProducts}>
        <Text style={style.productName}>1x 42 - Coca Cola 2L</Text>
     <View style={style.minus}></View>
    </View>
```

try this may be it can help you

```css
containerProducts: {
    paddingTop: 40,
    paddingLeft: 15,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
},
```

Comment: here i find the problem sorry first i didn't understand the question correctly but it working just replace the above css that i mentions for conatinerProducts

Comment: But created another problem when I put another small circle, there appeared a large space between them. At last I want to make two buttons (one more and one less) and among them a number. It's kind of a "shopping cart" where you can increase or decrease the quantity of the product.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you

Comment: rap them in a view so that, <view>b1andb2 </view> that view will be the view that contain circle in above view, and at least up-vote my answer. thanks

Comment: Thanks! This helped.